# How do I make these quotes appear in sequence everytime you refresh the page?

Tags: jquery

How do I make these quotes appear in sequence everytime you refresh the page?

```
<div id="demo"></div>

var Quotes = new Array();
var authors  = new Array();
Quotes[0] = '<h1>"Remarkable"</h1>'
authors[0] = '<h2>- Peter</h2>';
Quotes[1] = '<h1>"Wow"</h1>';
authors[1] = '<h2>- Heather </h2>';
Quotes[2] = '<h1>"Amazing"</h1>';
authors[2] = '<h2>- Kristen</h2>';
Quotes[3] = '<h1>"Great job"</h1>';
authors[3] = '<h2>- Lauren</h2>';

$(document).ready(function(){

 var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*Quotes.length);
 $('#demo').html( Quotes[rand]+authors[rand]);
});
```

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about doing a for loop?

Comment: You can use a [timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) or do you want it to change only on refresh? In that case you need to do some kind of [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)

Comment: IN sequence or in random? You are asking two different questions from what I see.

Comment: I just saw you using the random gen. You could use that if you wanted it to not always be in order, but still fall out the same way. Just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, whenever the page is refreshed you need to change the quote in sequence

```js
var Quotes = new Array();
var authors = new Array();
Quotes[0] = '<h1>"Remarkable"</h1>'
authors[0] = '<h2>- Peter</h2>';
Quotes[1] = '<h1>"Wow"</h1>';
authors[1] = '<h2>- Heather </h2>';
Quotes[2] = '<h1>"Amazing"</h1>';
authors[2] = '<h2>- Kristen</h2>';
Quotes[3] = '<h1>"Great job"</h1>';
authors[3] = '<h2>- Lauren</h2>';

$(document).ready(function() {
  var idx = localStorage.getItem('quote-index') != null ? (+localStorage.getItem('quote-index') + 1) : 0;
  idx = idx < Quotes.length ? idx : 0;

  $('#demo').html(Quotes[idx] + authors[idx]);
  localStorage.setItem('quote-index', idx)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0yppjo5s/)

Answer (score 0):

To do this in sequence I would just do something like below:

$(document).ready(function(){
        var html = ''; //init empty value

```
    for(var counter=0;counter<Quotes.length;counter++){           
       html += "</br>" + Quotes[counter] + authors[counter];
    }

    //now append it all
    $('#demo').html(html);   
});
```

A working fiddle found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/unix102/63amwwu4/)

Comment: As long as it is in the $(document).ready function or ;(function($){}) it will load in the page refresh or page load in sequential order.